# Counter in C displaying negative number

Tags: c, loops, counter

I've started recently to learn how to program in C. I'm following a class online and one of the projects we have to do is create a game where the computer comes up with a random number between two constants, and the user is supposed to find it with the minimal amount of tries possible.

I'm trying to implement a way of counting the tries each time the program passes through the loop (adding +1 to the counter) but all i get is that the number of tries is -472188416 whenever I execute the program as you can see here [Program after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBX1v.png). I don't understand why... Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I made :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    const int MIN = 1;
    int nombreMystere = 0, nombreUser = 0, continuerPartie = 1, MAX = 0, Niveau = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int compteurCoups = 1;

do
{
    printf("Bienvenue qu jeu du numero mystere\n");
    printf("Trouvez le bon numero en un minimum de coups\n\n");
    printf("Tapez 1 pour le mode facile\n");
    printf("Tapez 2 pour le mode moyen\n");
    printf("tapez 3 pour le mode difficile\n");


switch(Niveau)
{
    case 1:
    MAX = 10;
    nombreMystere = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

    case 2:
    MAX = 100;
    nombreMystere = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

    case 3:
    MAX = 1000;
    nombreMystere = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

    default:
        printf("Veuillez introduire un nombre entre 1 et 3 : ");
        scanf("%d", &Niveau);
    break;
}
do
    {
 printf("Quel est le nombre ? ");

    scanf("%d", &nombreUser);
    
    if (nombreUser > nombreMystere)
        {
            printf("C'est moins !\n");
            nombreUser++;
        }
    else if (nombreUser < nombreMystere)
       {
            printf("C'est plus !\n");
            nombreUser++;
       }
    else
        {
            printf("Bravo, vous avez trouve le nombre mystere en %d essais !!!\n"), compteurCoups;
            printf("Voulez vous rejouer ?\n");
            printf("Si oui appuyer sur 1, sinon si vous voulez quitter appuyez sur 2\n");
            scanf("%d", &continuerPartie);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }while (nombreUser != nombreMystere);
}while (continuerPartie == 1);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increase nombreuser in stead of compteurCoups.

Comment: I would also have a look at "(rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN".

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error :

```
printf("Bravo, vous avez trouve le nombre mystere en %d essais !!!\n"), compteurCoups;
```

Should be

```
printf("Bravo, vous avez trouve le nombre mystere en %d essais !!!\n", compteurCoups);
```

Don't forget that "compteurCoups" is an argument of the printf function. Thus, it belongs between the parenthesis after the function name.